# C program using inotify help in understanding code

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, inotify, bitwise-and

I was referring the man page for [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) and I came across this piece of code

```
               if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)
                   printf(" [directory]\n");
               else
                   printf(" [file]\n");
```

where event is a pointer to struct `inotify_event`.

- I couldn't understand this particular line `if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR)` and why a `bitwise AND` is used here.
- How was it determined that the `bitwise AND` is supposed to be used here and nothing else? It was not mentioned in the man page for inotify.

Comment: The page you link says *"The following bits may be set in the mask field returned by read(2): ... IN_ISDIR Subject of this event is a directory."* It's a different function but indicates this is a bit field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bitwise AND is masking out a specific bit (`IN_ISDIR`).  It is testing whether or not this one bit is set or not.  If this bit is set in `event->mask`, it evaluates to true.

For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FIRST_BIT  1
#define SECOND_BIT 2
#define THIRD_BIT  4

int main() {
  int x = 3;  /* 3 in binary is 011 */

  if ( x & FIRST_BIT )
    printf("First bit is set\n");
  if ( x & SECOND_BIT )
    printf("Second bit is set\n");
  if ( x & THIRD_BIT )
    printf("Third bit is set\n");
}
```

will give the output

```
    First bit is set
    Second bit is set
```

From `inotify.h`:

```
#define IN_ISDIR          0x40000000    /* event occurred against dir */
```

This value has only one bit set.  (In binary, this is `01000000000000000000000000000000`.)  A bitwise AND with this (0x40000000) and some variable will evaluate to either 0 (if the variable has a 0 here), or 0x40000000 if the variable has a 1 in the same place.  Any non-zero value is considered "true".

Logically, it is testing if the `event` was from a directory (instead of a file).

Comment: Nice and clean. Thank you @e0k

Answer (score 1):

A bitwise AND is just an easy (and very common) way to check if a specific bit is set.
The man page is clear that if that bit is set then the event is referring to a directory.